# Searching virtual machine linked clones in VMware Workstation

Tags: virtual-machine, search, vmware-workstation, clone, virtual-disk

Is there a tool which can search linked clones of a chosen virtual machine in selected directories?

Alternatively is there a tool which would show the path to the parent virtual disk of a selected virtual disk (`.vmdk` file)? This would make potential creation of the search tool much easier.

Answer (score 0):

### Script showing parent .vmdk file

There seems to be no tool which can show parent `.vmdk` file. Very good source of information for the script was [VMDK Handbook](http://www.sanbarrow.com/vmdk-handbook.html).

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

monstart=512    # header start in monolithic vmdk
monlen=1024     # header length in monolithic vmdk

err () { echo "$@" >&2 ; exit 1 ; }

test "$#" = 1 || err Usage: vmw-vmdk-parent disk-image.vmdk
test -f "$1" || err "$1" does not seem to be a file
test -r "$1" || err "$1" is not readable

(
if test $(stat -c %s "$1") -le 1500 ; then
    # separate header file (smaller than 1500 B)
    cat "$1"
else
    # monolithic vmdk file with embedded header
    dd if="$1" status=noxfer bs=1 skip=$monstart count=$monlen 2>/dev/null
fi
) |
    grep ^parentFileNameHint |
    sed 's/^parentFileNameHint="\([^"]*\)"$/\1/' ||
    err Error during processing "$1"
```

Comment: A script for searching linked clones will probably follow later :)